# GORM query conjunctions and disjunctions?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm a little confused about GORM query structures.

For instance, is the following:

```
Book.withCriteria{
    and {
        eq("author", "John")
        gt("publishDate", 2006)
    }
    or {
        gt("chapters", 12)
        gt("pages", 400)
    }
}
```

equivalent to the pseudo-code `(author == "John" && publishDate > 2006) && (chapters > 12 || pages > 400)` ?

Does that make the first `and` unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

Your translation is correct, and yes, the first and block is not needed. The default is always to and criterion together.

Comment: Note that your "pseudo code" will work in a `where` query: `Book.where{ (author == "John" && publishDate > 2006) && (chapters > 12 || pages > 400) }`